# File.Encrypt throwing "Parameter is incorrect"

Tags: vb.net, file-io, permissions, encryption

When I try to call System.IO.File.Encrypt() on an existing file, it throws a generic IOException, and the message is "Parameter is incorrect".

> System.IO.File.Encrypt("C:\Project\StorageDirectory\file.txt")

The current user the process is running under has full control to the "StorageDirectory" folder. Is there something I'm missing permissions-wise?

Comment: Addtional info: I'm impersonating a user at this code block (the impersonation works fine) while doing this. Also, since this is ASP.NET, I checked to see if the Network Service user (no code-level impersonation) gave the same error, but it encrypted the file just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.encrypt.aspx) say this could be caused by

> An I/O error occurred while opening
>   the file. -or- This operation is not
>   supported on the current platform.

It could be that the file is locked by another process, or that you don't have permission to modify it.  You could run [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) while you reproduce this error to see if that's your problem.

Comment: I'm guessing you're right about the file being locked, but by what, I don't know. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: I used ProcMon, and from what I saw, it suggested that the user needs certain rights to the entire path. I added the user to the local admin group, but still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Well reading [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.encrypt.aspx),

> An I/O error occurred while opening
>   the file.
>
> -or-
>
> This operation is not supported on the
>   current platform.

Neither is a particularly useful statement, but they should give you somewhere to start.

- Can you read the file? Have you tested it from within your app?
- Have you done encryption elsewhere? I've never seen encryption fail like that before (but there's always a first time!)

Comment: I will give your suggestion a shot.

Comment: Just tried it... I'm able to read the data from the file just before I try to encrypt the file.